# gulp.src pattern only matches last file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to browserify all my 'spec' files in my tests folder,

```
gulp.task('browserifyTests',function(){
return gulp.src(['./tests/**/spec*.js'])
    .pipe($$.browserify()
    )
    .pipe($$.rename('specs.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tests'));
```

});

I have 2 files specA.js and specB.js under tests/specs folder. When I browserify, I only see specB.js in the specs.bundle.js. Its really baffling why such a thing should happen when the pattern should clearly match here right? Or am I doing something silly..
Actually, I did a gulp-print and I see both file names printed too.

Comment: First thing first, try and use something like [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to check that your pattern matches your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't use Browserify in Gulp like that (because it's not a Gulp plugin).

Try this:

```
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const glob   = require('glob').sync;

gulp.task('js', () => {
  return $$.browserify(glob('./tests/**/spec*.js'), {...})
           .bundle()
           .pipe(source('specs.bundle.js'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./tests/'));
});
```

More info [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/gulp-browserify-starter-faq) (in particular, *"Using them together: Gulp + Browserify"*).

Comment: I shall try that, but why does it take that one file too? And it creates that spec.bundle.js with that 1 file in it along with its dependeices.

Comment: The `$$.browserify` most likely refers to `gulp-load-plugins`.

Comment: I am yet to try what @robertklep suggested. About $$.browserify,  yes it refers to gulp-load-plugins.